# Can't turn on wireless Lan on Lenovo E31-70 80KC! Key Problem?

Tags: networking, wireless, keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo

I am new to the forum and I hope that I don't violate any rules.

Two days ago I bought a new laptop (Lenovo E31-70 80KC) and directly installed ubuntu on it.

During the installation process I was asked to connect to a W-lan, I tried but it didn't work. It tried to connect then the screen freezed and I couldn't continue the installation process. After restarting the installation, the system was properly installed, but there were no W-Lan connections visible anylonger.

I can't even select the option. The option for wireless networks is just grey. And there stands that wireless networks are turned off. 
Usally I would just switch it on, but. Here is no switch at the laptop. It is just possible to use the key combination "Fn" + "F7". Unfortunately switching that combination has no effect.

Since two days I am searching through all threads and forums connected to the topic I can find. And I tried out almost everything but without success.

I updated my system on the latest version,
i tried to reset my BIOS and what else i found, but it is always the same:

> `rfkill list 0: hci0: Bluetooth
>
>   Soft blocked: yes
>
>   Hard blocked: no 
>   1: phy0: Wireless LAN
>
>   Soft blocked: no
>
>   Hard blocked: yes`

I am really not a computer guy, but I guess, that it has something to do that the function keys are turned of somehow. 
So I tried to change it under the keybord settings, but  I was just able to enable the keys "Fn2" (volume down) and "Fn3" (volume up). That was a little success. But I couldn't find any possibility to "turn on" the W-Lan button, because there is none such an option in the keybord menue to find. 
Of the  whole "Fn"-keys only 3 are working now: "Fn2", "Fn3" and "Fn9" (Blackscreen).

So what should I do now? Thank you for any help, I am really frustrated.

Edition:

```
 lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

brings:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: You have the driver. Does the `F7` key alone change the result of: `rfkill list all`? Is there any clue in the log? `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: No, pressing F7 alone or together with Fn makes no difference.

Comment: And how about the log?

Answer (score 0):

dmesg | grep iwl

brings:

```
 dmesg | grep iwl
```

[    9.807507] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: PCI->APIC IRQ transform: INT A -> IRQ 19

[   10.259645] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-15.ucode failed with error -2

[   10.259666] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode failed with error -2

[   10.462478] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm

[   10.932373] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164

[   10.933078] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

[   10.933562] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.

[   10.933587] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

[   10.970474] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'

[   11.008521] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at other askubuntu questions and related forum posts I've gathered that intel wireless 3160 is a dual card (bluetooth and wlan). There's some driver problem or design thing that makes it difficult for current iwl driver to use both at the same time. Disabling bluetooth migth enable wlan.

Try disabling bluetooth from bios. If that does not work, check out the links that provide moving/copying firmware files around.

Also it might be that newest ubuntu is needed (15.10 at the time of this post).

- https://askubuntu.com/a/632879/41757[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/632879/41757)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/567137/41757[2](https://askubuntu.com/a/567137/41757)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214075[3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214075)